# Share EntityManagerFactory between webapps?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have two different web applications running on my jetty server, both webapps depend on a jar file which includes my jpa files (like persistence.xml). When i start my server i see both webapps creating an EntityManagerFactory:

```
13:08:44.191 [main] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mypersunit'
```

and

```
13:09:05.063 [main] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mypersunit'
```

After the EntityManagerFactory is created it will create the c3p0 connection pool:

```
Aug 27, 2014 1:08:44 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
```

and

```
Aug 27, 2014 1:09:06 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
```

I'm using spring data jpa.

Is it possible to share the EntityManagerFactory related resources like the connection pool between the 2 web applications?

Cause now two EntityManagerFactory and connection pools are created.

Cheers!

Comment: You are not creating an EntityManager you are creating an EntityManagerFACTORY, very big diference betwen these 2. Can you provide the code to see where you are making your entity manager factory?

Comment: @Rat2000 i'm  not sure how i can see this, i was thinking because there a 2 c3p0 connection pools there are 2 entitymanagers. Will do a bit research.

Comment: There are 2 c3p0 because there are 2 EntityManagerFactory! An EntitymanagerFactory must be only 1, and from an entitymanagerFactory you can create as many EntityManagers as you want. I am not realy sure how you can fix this in Spring, I have to document this myself, but that is your problem from what I can gather

Comment: @Rat2000 I suspect i was a bit confused, entitymanager should indeed not be shared, but a EntityManagerFACTORY is threadsafe and can be a singleton. I was wondering if this EntityManagerFACTORY could be shared by two webapps, cause than there would also be only 1 connection pool. That does make a bit more sense ;-) [edit] updated my original question.

Comment: Yes you got it right, this is what I have been trying to say, you need 1 entitymanagerfactory for the 2 spring webapps that you have. now how you can manage to do that...well...I am not quite sure,not much experience with spring But I do have 1 question, why can't you leave it with 2 connections?

Comment: @Rat2000 it currently is indeed 2 connection pools, but in the future new webapps will be introduced and the number of connection pools will increase every time. I may be fooled by the long startup time of jetty but the data jpa layer might be quite resource heavy, better to have one of these than for every webapp one. (looking at it with keeping the hardware costs in mind)